# claim processing with policy variants using drools and jbpm?

Tags: drools, jbpm, business-rules

I'm trying to build an claim processing system. There will be multiple variations of insurance policies (based on the negotiations with individual clients). Aim is to keep a base policies per provider and then apply variations to them per client to ensure easy maintenance of top level policies (like damage due to fire covered or not). The policies should be easy to be created by non-technical business users.

What is the best approach for this? I'm thinking on the lines of using Drools to come up with basic rules and then create jBPM processes per policy provider that will consume the rules. Guvnor for authoring and maintenance of rules and processes.

Assuming no human tasks (its going to be just a set of rules that need to be fired and results be thrown out), is using jBPM going to be an overkill? Are there better alternatives in the open source world?

Answer (score 1):

Drools is already closely integrated with jBPM for use cases like this, so it definitely won't be overkill, they will work very nicely together.  jBPM is not only about human interactions, it can just as well be used for automatic processing.

One remark, it might even be possible to not have one process per provider but have only one (or a small set of) process(es) and use rules to handle the variations.